# Is it possible to nest QueuedTaskSchedulers?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I try to achieve the following scenario:

```
TaskScheduler HighPrioScheduler = new QueuedTaskScheduler().ActivateNewQueue(0);
TaskScheduler MediumPrioScheduler = new QueuedTaskScheduler().ActivateNewQueue(1);
TaskScheduler LowPrioScheduler = new QueuedTaskScheduler().ActivateNewQueue(2);

void HandleWebRequest(SomeRequest request)
{
    if(request.Prio == Prio.High)
        HandleWebRequestWithScheduler(request, new QueuedTaskScheduler(HighPrioScheduler, 4));
    if(request.Prio == Prio.Medium)
        HandleWebRequestWithScheduler(request, new QueuedTaskScheduler(MediumPrioScheduler, 4));
    if(request.Prio == Prio.Low)
        HandleWebRequestWithScheduler(request, new QueuedTaskScheduler(LowPrioScheduler, 4));
}
```

I want to have 3 global priority scheduling queues, so that tasks created by high priority WebRequestHandlers will execute first. Furthermore all WebRequestHandlers should have a limited degree of parallelism. Is that approach feasible using the QueuedTaskScheduler from the [ParallelExtensionsExtra](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/) library?

Comment: Although this is an interesting exercise, what problem are you fundamentally trying to solve? Or is this just for academic purposes? I mean if you really want to go down this path, i would look at modifying a simple task scheduler to give you the priorities and using TPL dataflow. Or baking your own propagator system which gives priority based on something. However this is going to take a lot of work and i am just not sure how much gain you will get out of it. Which brings me back to if there is some problem you are trying to solve or running into?

Comment: This is for a huge backend where hundrets of requests need to handled in parallel. Some requests have a higher priority than others and should be handled first, as well as the task they create. However no single request handler should be able to exhaust the whole thread pool.

Comment: @MichaelRandall
^